# Notations in book

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

In measure theory and Lebesgue integration book by wheeden and zygmund there is one notation upper arrow  from bottom left corner to upper right corner defined as increase to, somewhere in question  it used as $f_n$ increases to $f$. What does it mean?  Where $f_n$ is sequence of functions.

Comment: It means that $f_n(x)$ is an increasing sequence of numbers for each fixed $x$ in the domain, and $f_n $ converges to $f$ pointwise (or perhaps almost everywhere).

Comment: It means $(f_n)$ is an  increasing sequence of functions, monotonically converging to $f$.